# JFrog Helm repository always returns 404

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jfrog-container-registry

I've got 3 helm repositories in my JFrog account:

- helm-local - intended to store private helm charts
- helm-remote - intended to proxy public charts
- helm - virtual one, unites both above

I configure my helm client like this: `helm repo add %reponame% https://%name%.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm --username %username% --password %password%` as it's descrbed in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Helm+Chart+Repositories.
Then I do `helm repo update`.

But when I try to do `helm pull %reponame%/%chartname%`, it returns 404

```
Error: failed to fetch https://%name%.jfrog.io/helm-local/%chartname%-%chartversion%.tgz : 404 Not Found
helm.go:88: [debug] failed to fetch https://%name%.jfrog.io/helm-local/%chartname%-%chartversion%.tgz : 404 Not Found
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter.(*HTTPGetter).get
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter/httpgetter.go:90
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter.(*HTTPGetter).Get
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter/httpgetter.go:42
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader.(*ChartDownloader).DownloadTo
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader/chart_downloader.go:99
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Pull).Run
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/pull.go:129
main.newPullCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/pull.go:75
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

It seems fetching an index, and gets the latest version of the chart, but can't get a correct download URL of it.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying to pull from helm-local directly; use the helm virtual and try to pull. Also, perform a zap cache on the virtual repo and recalculate the index on the local repo and test the pull.

Comment: I actually used helm virtual, but the index that was downloaded, contains references to helm-local. I also tried to recalculate the index in JFrog UI, and that helped - the links in index became correct! Thank you!